# Bootcamp usage and size vastly different when checked in Mac vs Windows

Tags: bootcamp, partition

I had some issues signing into Windows 10 on a Bootcamp partition, and even got the BSOD a one juncture.  It was all coming fast and furious, so I don't recall exactly what happened when.  But now Windows diskmgr shows Bootcamp C: with a capacity of 102.27GB and free space at 56.39GB, but in the lower section of the diskmgr window shows a partition size of 232.67GB, which is about what it should be.

I was going to use the expand filesystem command to try to correct it, but then I checked the drive with the Mac Disk Utility.  It shows the Bootcamp partition at 249.82GB (again roughly what I set it up to be as I recall), but it shows a usage 189.22GB and free space at 60.6GB.  So I was hesitant to use the expand filesystem command as it seems something is filling up the drive.  Any suggestions as to how to correct this will be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Windows is reporting GiB instead of GB. Also, looks like Mac is determining usage by subtracting free space from partition size. The table below was built from the values given in the OP's question.

|  | Windows diskmgr | Mac Disk Utility |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Usage |  | 189.22 GB |
| Free Space | 56.39 GiB = 60.55 GB | 60.6 GB |
| Capacity | 102.27 GiB = 109.81 GB |  |
| Partition Size | 232.67 GiB = 249.83 GB | 249.82 GB |

Where 1.07374 GB = 1 GiB.

> The capacity is the size of the NTFS file system, which in your case is significantly smaller than the partition size.

You should be able to use the Microsoft interactive `diskpart` command to extend the NTFS file system to end of the containing partition. After setting the correct focus, run the following command from the `diskpart` command interpreter:

```
EXTEND FILESYSTEM
```

### References

- [GB to GiB Conversion](https://www.gbmb.org/gb-to-gib)
- [diskpart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/diskpart)